# Why isn't my global variable recognised in other modules in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

This is what I have in the "ThisWorkbook" module:

```
Option Explicit

Public wbReport As Workbook

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set wbReport = ActiveWorkbook
End Sub
```

I have the following macro in the module corresponding to a cetain worksheet, I want it to activate when the values of certain cells change:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = wbReport.Range("inspection_number")

    etc.    
    .
    .
    .
End Sub
```

However, when this macro is activated, I get an runtime error '424' as if the wbReport global variable had never been established.

Any suggestions?

Comment: ```wbReport ``` is not just simple variable but it is member of class ```ThisWorkbook```. So it is needed to reference this variable with the name of the class like ```ThisWorkbook.wbReport```.

Comment: And becasue ```wbReport``` is workbook it is necessary to say on which sheet the range is located e.g. ```ThisWorkbook.wbReport.ActiveSheet.Range("inspection_number")```.

Comment: Also remember that a `Workbook` object doesn't have a `Range` property - that belongs to either a `Worksheet` or the `Application`.

Comment: @GuyH don't forget to use ```Option Explicit``` it helps to catch a lot of errors.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33798766/variable-between-worksheet-and-module-not-cooperating/33799649#33799649) another question which is almost identical to yours. HTH

Comment: OK, thanks dee, that seems to have fixed it. Would this have been avoided if the global variable were declared in an inserted module? I wanted it in ThisWorkbook because I want to assign it its value with the auto open macro.

Comment: When you do it like this then the variable ```wbReport``` actually duplicates the property ```ThisWorkbook```. So you do not really need this varaible but can use ```ThisWorkbook```. Or if you wish you can declare a public ```global``` variable in standard module. Then you can reference to this varaible just with its name.

Answer (score 0):

`wbReport` must be available as an object.  When you run `Worksheet_Change()`, have you beforehand run `Set wbReport = ActiveWorkbook`? The error message indicates not.  The Locals window is also useful to find out:  set a break point and see if `wbReport` is an object.  If not, find a way to make is so.  You may be able to use `Workbook_Open()` to do just that, but you will have to make it `public` instead of `private`.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Call Workbook_Open()
    '' the Call keyword is optional, I find it adds clarity.

    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = wbReport.Range("inspection_number")

    etc.
```

Instead of calling that function, simper to just use its one line of code:

```
Set wbReport = ActiveWorkbook
```

I perceive you come from an object-oriented background, where the module would contain its methods and some would be called implicitly.  (I don't, so my descriptive verbiage is probably incorrect.)  This makes your approach a bit formalistic.  This will serve you well generally; in this case, perhaps an unnecessary layer.

Comment: I have tried changing  'Workbook_Open()' to 'Public' but I'm still getting the same error. As you can see, in 'Workbook_Open', I have 'Set wbReport = ActiveWorkbook', so I'd expect that to be enough to establish it as an object

Comment: You have to call `Workbook_Open()`.   See edited answer.